# Scroll inside an EditText which is in a ScrollView

Tags: android, scroll

Is it possible to scroll inside an EditText which is in a `ScrollView`?

```
<ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- scroll inside this EditText -->
            <EditText android:id="@+id/et_scrollhere"
                android:lines="6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Voorbeeld"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Or is it possible to have the EditText embedded in the keyboard in portrait mode? Something like WhatsApp, that EditText is scrollable.

Comment: Use only android:scrollbars="vertical" remove <ScrollView>...

Comment: I need to scroll inside my linearLayout aswell.

Comment: Fix height of EditText instead of wrap content.

Comment: You have to Create custom Scrollview class where you should handle Intercept Touch. here is the reference link [HELPFUL LINK.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920137/android-viewpager-and-horizontalscrollview)

Comment: I changed my mind using a scrollable EditText. Instead I'm now using a EditText that grows with the text.

Answer (score 43):

```
EditText dwEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DwEdit);       
dwEdit.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (view.getId() ==R.id.DwEdit) {
                        view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        switch (event.getAction()&MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

And in your xml file

```
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/DwEdit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minLines="10"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences">
        </EditText>
```

I hope it will help you ..

Comment: awesome!!! works well!

Comment: Thanks ...user1840899

Comment: I was searching for this for a very long time

Comment: Is it helpful to you ?

Comment: yes amsheer,it is very useful

Comment: Fantastic Work Brother @Amsheer

Comment: But the parent scrollview also scrolls along with the edittext scroll when the content is big enough.. How to overcome that?