# Edittext is not scrollable in scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, parallax, android-tablayout

I created the parallax effect in that screen three tabs are created and multiple editext in every tabs. so when i have scroll outside of editext then it scroll no issues but when i scroll on edittext then screen is not scroll.
    mainactivity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_group_details"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout_Myprofile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_my_profile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="5dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/white">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativelayout_profilepic"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                    tools:context=".MainActivity"
                    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">


                    <com.oi.managemygroup.util.SelectableRoundedImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView_of_my_profile_ampl"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_avtar_new"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        app:sriv_border_color="@color/bluecolor"
                        app:sriv_border_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="@dimen/corner_radius_for_mmg_images"
                        app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="@dimen/corner_radius_for_mmg_images"
                        app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="@dimen/corner_radius_for_mmg_images"
                        app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="@dimen/corner_radius_for_mmg_images" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textview_userName_amps"
                        android:text="User Name"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blackcolor"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_of_my_profile_ampl"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_of_my_profile_ampl"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true">


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view_Vertical_Line">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView_forum_created_count_Text_ampl"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Forums\ncreated"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView_forum_created_count_ampl"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:text="0"
                                android:textColor="#0c83bd"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view_Vertical_Line" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/view_Vertical_Line"
                            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:background="#E5E5E5"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view_Vertical_Line">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView_forum_participated_count_Text_ampl"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Forums \n participate"
                                android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView_forum_participated_count_ampl"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                                android:text="0"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:textColor="#0c83bd"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/textView_forum_participated_count_Text_ampl"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view_Vertical_Line" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>


            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_my_profile"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_my_profile_screenr" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tablinear_layout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout_of_profile"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_Horizontal_Line"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height=".5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout_of_profile"
                android:background="#E5E5E5"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pagerofprofile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view_Horizontal_Line"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_layout_footer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/bluecolor" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

and tab1.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_Address_details"

            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:weightSum="7">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_address1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:text="@string/address1"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_address1_ampl"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress|textMultiLine"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    android:lines="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_address2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:text="@string/address2"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_address2_ampl"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress|textMultiLine"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    android:lines="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_address3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:text="@string/address3"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_address3_ampl"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress|textMultiLine"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_city"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:text="@string/city"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_city_ampl"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_state"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:text="@string/state"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_state_ampl"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_country"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:text="@string/country"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_country_ampl"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_pin"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:text="@string/pin"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_pin_ampl"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="8"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#B3B3B3"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe because the editText is stealing the focus, and the framework cannot detect the swipe for the scrolling to occur.

Comment: on edittext scroll you have to ignore parent scroll using touchevent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896839/scroll-inside-an-edittext-which-is-in-a-scrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770252/scrolling-editbox-inside-scrollview).

```
EditText EtOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        EtOne.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        if (v.getId() == R.id.comment1) {
                            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your EditText is capturing your scroll (as EditTexts can scroll horizontally too).

To resolve your issue you will have to call;

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

so it cannot steal focus. You will have to also attach a click listener onto your `EditText` which will then turn the focuses back on and focus it.

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editText.setFocusable(true);
                editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
                editText.setFocused(true)
            }
        });
```

You may also have to put a listener for focus changing and turn the focuses off again when it looses focus! Basically you will have to do everything manually. It is recommended in the Android Guidelines to never put an `EditText` within a `ScrollView` so to do it you'll have to be very 'hacky' and you'd probably be better off just changing the flow of your app.

Comment: you still can't scroll when touching the `EditText`s? Have you implemented everything I mentioned?

Comment: yes i implement everything that you mention and i scroll when touch to edittext but still it's not works for me.......