# How to add a scrollbar to an edit text

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, scrollbar

I was wondering how I can add a scrollbar to an edit text whenever the text is too long and can't be seen on the edit text box.

Something like this:
[image]

Any ideas? I've tried setting it through the xml but so far it hasn't worked, it just moves if I drag my finger over it but no bar is visible.

Comment: Try looking at [Enabling scrollbar in edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4319456/16653700).

Answer (score 0):

You can add `fadeScrollbars="false"` in your xml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you for answering but that, unfortunately, does not seem to work

Comment: How about you put your textview inside HorizontalScrollView and set the `fadeScrollbars="false"` to the scrollview, not the textview?